# Public and private hosts in the same BIND zone

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, bind

For my particular setup, I've got control of a BIND 9 zone file for, say, `example.com`.  There are several hosts in this zone, such as `www.example.com` and `mail.example.com`.  I want the public internet to be able to query these hosts and retrieve their IPs as you'd expect.

Can some hosts be flagged as "private", in the sense that most public internet users can't query information about these hosts, except for a specific IP range of users?  For example, can I make a third host, `secret.example.com` query-able only by users in the `192.168.0.x` range?

I'm aware that I can do this with separate zones in BIND, but this doesn't seem to offer what I need.  The key here is that both the public and private hosts need to be part of the same parent, `example.com` in this case.  This could also be achieved by the `/etc/hosts` file on the few privy machines, but then the records would not be centrally manageable.

Is this possible, or am I overlooking a different solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, Bind does this with **views**. Some in detailed examples are [here](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/oreilly/networking/news/views_0501.html) and [here](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/view.html).

It would look something like this in named.conf:

```
view "trusted" {
 match-clients { 192.168.23.0/24; }; // our network
  recursion yes;
  zone "example.com" {
   type master;
   // private zone file including local hosts
   file "internal/master.example.com";
  };
  // add required zones
 };
view "badguys" {
 match-clients {"any"; }; // all others hosts
 // recursion not supported
 recursion no;
 };
 zone "example.com" {
   type master;
   // public only hosts
   file "external/master.example.com";
  };
  // add required zones
 };
```

One trick I typically do to make administration easier is to simply have the internal file **$INCLUDE** the external file -- just don't forget about SOAs.

As a final word of caution, don't pretend this is anything more than Rubber Chicken Security (not that there's anything wrong with that).

Comment: This is perfect!  Now I just need to read up on how to get this to properly transfer to slave servers.

Comment: I should mention that I got BIND views working perfectly, complete with zone transfers to slaves.  The biggest hangup for me was discovering that slaves required a second IP each to retrieve the zones for each view.